# logrotate is not working

Tags: linux, logrotate

I did configuration inside logrotate.d for tomcat catalina.out and fixed the size to 200M below are my config file:

```
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/logs/catalina.out {
    copytruncate
    size 200M
    rotate 20
    compress
    missingok
    daily
}
```

but unfortunately it does not run even the log cross 900 MiB. I have to manually run the command `logrotate -f tomcat`. The manual execution works so I believe my configuration is right.

DO I need to reboot the box or anything need to be done to get this file executed.
I even tried by removing `daily` from the file but nothing changed. 
This is first time I am configuring the logrotate.

Comment: Do you have `logrotate` running as eg. a `cron` job?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its not setup to run in the cron. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/ provides a good overview

Comment: Hi Cordonus, Thank you for your reply. I have gone through the shared link and below are my observation: once I ran crontab -l    it says no crontab for root. After that I configured the job like:                              @daily /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat and 
0 0 * * * /etc/logrotate.conf                                                                            
I hope this will work, I will be observing the log change. please share your feedback if you feel any improvement.

Comment: even after adding the logrotate in cron job, it is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say I'm not sure what else it could be other than possibly file permission issues.